# Calculating Time of Day

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I want to calculate a text field call "TIME_DAY," depending of whether or not the time falls within of four time periods it should return one of four values. My script should work, but it doesn't.

[image]

[image]

```
def timeday(time, am, diur, pm, noc):
    if(time >=am AND time < diur):
        return “cerp_am”
    elif(time>= diur AND time<pm):
        return “diurnal”
    elif(time>=pm AND time<noc):
        return “cerp_pm”
    else:
        return “nocturnal”
```

---

```
 timeday(!LMT_TIME!, !B_C_AM1!, !B_DIUR1!, !B_C_PM1!, !BEG_NOC1!)
```

I'm getting ERROR 000989: Python syntax error: Parsing error Syntax.

Here is what my attribute table looks like:[image]

@Midavalo's solution worked well for the vast majority of my data, except for a few datasets, where it mistakenly places midnight values in the "diurnal" category. [image]

Comment: What are the values in the fields you are looking up?

Comment: Times: so if time in LMT_TIME falls between the time in B_C_AM1 and B_DIUR, it should return "cerp_am".

Comment: Midavalo, please see the edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing actual values for your fields it's hard to answer, but for a syntax error I imagine it may be the uppercase `AND`.  Change this to `and`

```
def timeday(time, am, diur, pm, noc):
    if(time >=am and time < diur):
        return "cerp_am"
    elif(time>= diur and time<pm):
        return "diurnal"
    elif(time>=pm and time<noc):
        return "cerp_pm"
    else:
        return "nocturnal"
```

Python is case sensitive, so most operators in python should be in lower case only.

Additionally, you will need to fix the quote marks - `“` and `”` should be `"`.  These odd quote marks happen when you copy/paste into and out of something like Microsoft Word as it likes to be helpful and automatically change characters to others that it thinks look nice, but don't flow well into syntax/format dependant code like Python.

Comment: I'm still getting ERROR 000989: Python syntax error: Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @J.W.Powell Fix the quote marks `“` and `”` should be `"`

Comment: @J.W.Powell assuming that you're writing your code in WordPad or similar, you could try using [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to avoid the dreaded smart quotes being inserted.

Comment: @Midavalo, this script (or some variation of it) worked perfectly to edit 95% of my data. The only exception is one folder of data, which for some reason, it misidentifies all the times near midnight. The script runs fine, but if the 'TIME' value begins with a zero, it identifies it as "diurnal." Do you have any guesses as to why this might be?

Comment: I was able to fix it, but I had to create a new 'TIME' field. To create the new time field, I used the following script:
`!Existing_TIME_FIELD!.zfill(8)`